# Correct way to setup IdentityServer4 Cookies for login, JWT token for API authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, identityserver4

We have one application that uses an IdentityServer4 cookies authorization scheme for user login like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.Authority = <local IDP server with IdentityServer4>;
            options.ClientId = <ClientId>;
            options.ClientSecret = <secret>
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        })
```

The client on the IDP looks like this:

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientId = <ClientID>,
    ClientName = <ClientName>,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
    RequireConsent = true,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret(<secret>.Sha256()) },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RedirectUris = { "http://" + ip + "/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://" + ip + "/signout-callback-oidc" },
    AllowedScopes = {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
        }
};
```

We also have a WebAPI located at /api/...

The goal is to add JWT Bearer Token authorization to the API. For that I have added the following code:

```cs
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            jwtOptions.Authority = <local IDP server with IdentityServer4>;
            jwtOptions.Audience = <ClientID>
            jwtOptions.SaveToken = true;
        })
```

The API is guarded with

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

After login, I get the token with

```cs
await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

However, when I try to use that token to access the API, I get the following error:

> AuthenticationFailed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'http://localhost:50059/resources'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: ClientID or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

And indeed, when I decode the token using jwt.io, `aud` is set to `http://localhost:50059/resources`, while the ClientID appears as a new field `'client_id': '<ClientID>'`.

What I found out so far suggests that `aud` is always set to `<idp>/resources` for access tokens and that API access is handled with scope claims inside the token. However, I do not understand how to set that up correctly.

Does anybody know where the problem lies and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the solution was quite simple. As suspected, it had to do with scopes. I tried to solve that earlier but it kept saying "invalid scopes"...because I never created the API resource, duh.

1. Create new API resource in your IDP server
   `new ApiResource("api-name", "API Name")`
2. Add new API resource as AllowedScope to Client
   `client.AllowedScopes.Add("api-name")`
3. Ask for Scope in OpenIdConnect authentication
   `options.Scopes.Add("api-name")`
4. Set Audience (or ApiName if using IdentityServer authentication handler) to API resource
   `options.Audience = "api-name"`
   or
   `options.ApiName = "api-name"`

With that I was now able to use the access token to access my API.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement it like this in your startup to have both JWT and cookie authentication:

```
  builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "YOUR AUTH API ADDRESS";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddPolicyScheme("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "JWT_OR_COOKIE", options =>
        {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
            {
                string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
                {
                    return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }

                return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            };
        });

    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "Identity.Application")
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(m => m.DefaultPolicy = policy);
```